# How can I show appreciation to team members when I'm promoted?

Tags: employer-relations, internship

I have been an intern in a company for the past 5 months. As I started here I was assigned into a project that happened to start around my starting date. We have a planning session for the last sprint of the project and I wanted to show some appreciation to the team members that I have had which helped me to make the best out of my internship. I am looking for different ways to do so and not to come out as creepy/awkward/minion/ass-kisser and etc. It's worth mentioning that I will be working as a permanent hire within couple of weeks!

Update: I work in US and my team members are mainly 40 to 50 plus one person in 20s like myself.

Comment: I like your attitude and here's wishing for a good carrer for you :) Hope you get the answer you're looking for. Knowing the average age of your coworkers, the country you're in and the area you work on might help us give suggestions.

Comment: Thank you Renan. You bring up some good points which will help get better answers, I am going to update the question accordingly.

Comment: Food does usually work, but it shouldn't be extravagant. I usually try for something a bit different, especially with older co-workers -- perhaps cheese & crackers, fruit, something not-full-of-sugar and interesting.

Answer (score 15):

It is very common in my company (US, fairly casual engineering culture) to celebrate promotions and life events (birthdays, marriages, anniversaries, etc.) by bringing in treats for your team and others you work with. Generally that is donuts/bagels in the morning time, or ice cream treats after lunch. Some folks like to go above and beyond and bring in home-made treats as well. It's a good opportunity to get all those folks you worked with to swing by your desk, and have a conversation where you can thank them and possibly share project stories.

For team members that are leaving, either moving to a different team or leaving the company, we usually do a group lunch with all of the folks they worked with. Usually this is done as a "surprise" to the person, though there is no reason they couldn't set one up themselves.

I think either of these is an easy, well-appreciated way to thank your team members, both with treats and getting them to chat with you in person.

Comment: Donuts and/or bagels are a great suggestion. They always went down well where I used to work in the US.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: I agree with the first part but the second part? I don't interact with half of the people in my row on a regular basis and handing them treats is awkward -- Peter K.: I have been doing donuts for most of the planning sessions so I need to do something more than that this time to make my point!

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I have found that having a bonbonniere in my desk really breaks the ice and leads people from the nearby desks into socializing, not only with me but with each other as well.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere so I just checked that in English it means something else than we use that word for in Brazil. I was kinda ashamed when I did a Google image search. I don't mean anything fancy, just a piece of transparent plastic or glass, full of candies inside. Keep it open so people get the message that they can grab some for free. In some work places it is the conversation-starting equivalent of a water cooler.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yes, they are. I buy them in packets of a hundred each, they're pretty cheap.

Comment: Just as a FYI not everyone can/will eat doughnuts, etc., and you might unwittingly come off as insensitive. To people deep in the paleo or wheat-free movement, you might even be viewed as somewhat malicious as they basically view these kinds of foods as poisons. (Disclosure: I think they are as well, but wouldn't necessarily feel like someone innocently offering me these things is deliberately trying to poison me.)

Comment: @Nomz If donuts is the standard thing then bring in an actual cake, or cupcakes instead. Just doing something different is likely enough to show that you are appreciative, it doesn't have to be really showy.

Comment: @Nomz Don't go and hand out treats - put them on your desk where people can come and get one. Then send out an email saying donuts/bagels are available for anyone who wants one, and saying why you are celebrating.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship that is very true. My company is fairly multicultural, so options are always a good idea!

Comment: @AmyBlankenship, this is very interesting. I was clueless about this. I keep that in mind. Thanks.

Comment: @DJClayworth, ahhh, that makes more sense. I either read it wrongfully or had a bad understanding of the comment. That raises another question for me! I have seen many female co worker doing that however, I have never seen any guy coworker doing so. How has everyone else observation been?

Comment: I think that's just because women are more likely to think to do it, for a variety of reasons.